# Breaking the debugger whenever delete/delete[] is called in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I might be missing something very trivial but is there a way to pause/break the debugger whenever any `delete` or `delete[]` is called? I tried `Debug->New Breakpoint->Function` Breakpoint (typed in delete as the function name) but it doesn't really trigger.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You want to break on the deallocation or on the object(s) destructors being executed?

Comment: While my answer might help you, I'm very curious about *why* you want to do this? What is the *real* problem you're having? What is the reason you want to break on `delete` and `delete[]`? Perhaps we can help you with the actual problem you're having? So please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Use "operator delete" for the function name.  Also covers delete[].

Comment: @HansPassant worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Currently tracking a suspected de-allocation overshoot crash which only happens in release. Back tracking the commits won't work as the bug is introduced when we upgraded the source from VS2015 to VS2017. 

With the amount of dynamic memory allocation/deallocation in our source code, it's one way I could think of to track it down.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`delete` and `delete[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) are *operators* in expressions, not functions.

They do however call operator functions that can be overloaded (and used to set breakpoint on). These are named [`operator delete` and `operator delete[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete).